# pdf first page display as a div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an object in html displaying a pdf document. What I want is

1. disable the scrollbar (none of the methods like scrollbar:no or border adjustment worked for me)
2. Make the object behave like a link, instead as a document.

Ultimately, I used the object method, because I wanted to display the fist page of a pdf document located somewhere at a server in a frame of the browser (as a div). Is there any other (easier) way how this can be done?

Comment: Have you set the div to have a style of `overflow:hidden;` so that its scrollbars are hidden as well as the iframes

Comment: And what do you mean "used the object method" or do you mean the object tag